# Understanding groups in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, user-accounts

**How can you run the following pseudo-command?**

```
sudo chown :twin::rwx /usr/local/copyrightLinux
```

I want that each user in the group twin can read, write and execute all files which belong to the group twin. The apparent problem is with permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo chown :twin /usr/local/copyrightLinux

sudo chmod g=rwx /usr/local/copyrightLinux
```

Comment: Note, could also use "sudo chgrp twin /usr/local/copyrightLinux" for the first command. Seems like it might be a bit easier to understand rather than wondering why there's a floating colon in the middle of chown.